# How much portion of the given text will be displayed in a TextView

Tags: android

i want to develop an ebook reader..
can i know how much text will be displayed on the given textview whose dimension is `match_parent`.
or can i get the visible text of the textview... (if i copy the whole text on the textview)

i have tried various things like `Paint:breakText`.. it returns me the chars to be displayed in given width,
but i dont understand how many lines will the textview have... so i cannot determine how many times i should loop the `Paint:breakText`..

also `TextView:getLineCount` returns 0,
`TextView:height` returns -1 (bcz i have set it to match_parent)

plz help me out wid this..

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322339/how-to-get-height-of-text-with-fixed-width-and-get-text-length-which-fits-in-a-f

Answer (score 0):

If you provide your textView's height  with matchparent and enclose your textview within a scrollview, I think you can accommodate large amount of text within a single textview.

Comment: no.. my requirement is diffrent.. i dnt wanna scroll.. i wanna only display the text that wud be visible in this view (without scrolling) & den m using a view Flipper.. i.e wen the page is turned, it will display the rest of the contents in continuity of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe FontMetrics will help? You can see the doc for FontMetrics here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.FontMetrics.html

Comment: i dont think this will help.. as i need the **TextView** height.. wen i specify it in the layout as 'match_parent'