# TextView - get Visible text, and how to divide string to pages?

Tags: android, textview

What i want to do is to divide long text to pages, so I can display them one by one in one text view, when user hits next/prev button. What I need is to know te last displayed character index, but thats not so simple....

I have tried this:

```
int start = textView.getLayout().getLineStart(0);
int end = textView.getLayout().getLineEnd(textView.getLineCount() - 1);

String displayed = textView.getText().toString().substring(start, end);
```

frrom [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636946/get-current-visible-text-in-textview)

But getLayout returns null

Also using getWidth/getHeight is useless cause they returns 0 in "onCreate" function...

Thanks for any help !

Comment: `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` return 0 in `onCreate()` because the metrics for the screen haven't been determined yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might make more sense to approach the problem from the other direction: You have a long `String` of text.  Then you decide how much you can fit on a page, and break the `String` into an array of multiple substrings, one for each page.  Then you can simply store a page index someplace, and use that as an index into the array of `String` that you made when you broke the entire text into substrings.

This assumes that there's an algorithm to find how much text you can fit in a page.  Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322339/how-to-get-height-of-text-with-fixed-width-and-get-text-length-which-fits-in-a-f).

Comment: OK - that was usefull.  Now I want to use:  getPaint().breakText(mock_string,true, width , null);
But.... how can I get textView Width in "onCreate" ? 
tried: 
contentText.measure(0, 0);
int width = contentText.getMeasuredWidth();
But now width has no sense (about 14k)

Comment: You can't get width from `View.getWidth()` in `onCreate` because that information hasn't been passed down to the Views yet.  However, try this to get general screen metrics: `DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);`  That will give you height and width of the entire screen in pixels.  Depending on your layout, you might have enough information there to determine (or make a good enough guess about) your TextView's width.

Comment: It looks like you really helped me. I Measured my display, and loaded from dimension my paddings and margins. Then I calculated actual textview width, and method breakText() seems to be working well. When i finnish my method i will post it as answer since, lot of people asked simmilar questions.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a much efficient way to display a long string across number of pages.                 -I display the long text into the text view and disable scrolling                                  -I then find out the lines in the layout and lines on single screen, hence I know how many screens(pages) will the long string span across                                                        -Then whenever user clicks a button to go to next page or swipes screen to go to the next page then I use TexView.scrollTo() function to move to number of lines(as many on a screen) forward. So it becomes as good as moving to next page